# How to order items in tuples?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have pairs of numbers and I want to sort them.

```
grunt> dump unordered
(11,22)
(88,33)
(55,66)
```

How do I sort them to:
(11,22)
(33,88)
(55,66)

Tried to use bags:
grunt> bag_of_pairs = foreach unordered generate TOBAG(TOTUPLE($0),TOTUPLE($1));
grunt> ordered = foreach bag_of_pairs {o1 = order $0 by $0; generate o1;}

And ended up with this ordered, but over-wrapped list, that I don't know how to simplify:

```
grunt> dump ordered
({(11),(22)})
({(33),(88)})
({(55),(66)})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/udf.html#python-udfs) to convert the bag to a tuple. However, since you only need to order two items this can also be done with a [bincond](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#arithmetic).

```
ordered = FOREACH unordered GENERATE ($0<$1?$0:$1), ($0<$1?$1:$0) ;
```

**NOTE:** I can't test this right now, but this should also work.

```
ordered = FOREACH unordered GENERATE FLATTEN(($0<$1?($0,$1):($1,$0)) ;
```